# Is there an automatic way of showing Google reviews summary (aggregation) in your search result rich snippet or is it always hardcoded?

Tags: google-search, schema.org, google-rich-snippets, structured-data

I've read through the docs on how to add the aggregated reviews in your search result as rich snippet, but all docs explain that you should manually hardcode the review summary (i. e. number of reviews and star rating) in your ld+json structured data within your website.

Doesnt that mean that you manually have to update this data every time a new review comes in or your average star rating changes? Did I miss something? Isnt there a way to "just look at the Google ratings" and show them in the search result, too? Whats best practice here?

Comment: By Google ratings, are you talking about reviews on a Google Business Profile? These reviews show up in local listing results and not in results from your website. Their guidelines say you can't mark them up on your site. https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2019/09/making-review-rich-results-more-helpful#updated

Answer (score 2):

You would need JavaScript to query an API and obtain the reviews information to produce the markup on your page.

For products, there’s no such Google API:

> currently, there is no such google api for product ratings/reviews.

https://support.google.com/google-ads/thread/108957491?hl=en&msgid=108960347

For business reviews, there is a Google API:

- https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data

but Google do not show rich results when the review markup is for your own Organization or LocalBusiness:

> we're not going to display review rich results anymore for the schema types LocalBusiness and Organization (and their subtypes) in cases when the entity being reviewed controls the reviews themselves.

https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2019/09/making-review-rich-results-more-helpful#self-serving-reviews-arent-allowed-for-localbusiness-and-organization.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I find this wildly confusing. The dentist is also on Facebook and the Google search result shows the ratings on that Facebook teaser although these are Facebook ratings... isnt Facebook controlled by Facebook? So in other words, if you have Google ratings on your business account you cannot show those summarized as rich snippet on your search result?

Comment: Facebook does not control the dentist so the reviews are not self-serving. Another way of putting it is that review aggregators showing reviews for multiple other businesses can get review stars. But the business itself can't on the site it owns. Blame it on businesses spamming Google with fake structured data.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath True, but it is very weird that the reviews are to be manually added to your site in the first place. I'd love for a tag like `<snippet show="ratings" googleid="">` and voila

Comment: I believe there are plugins/extensions for some CMSes that will let you do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

hope you have found a solution and sorry for not replying last year.
The script below calls an api on au2matic.com which returns accumulated customer reviews. It costs 10-15 USD per month but can be tested for free.

Good luck

Just copy below in bottom of header on website

```html
<p style="font-size:1%;" id="a2mjson"></p>
<Script>
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'https://au2mailer.com/api/a2m-getschemaorg.asp?apikey=f457c545a9ded88f18ecee47145a72c0&prod=44');
request.send();
request.onload = ()=>{
document.getElementById("a2mjson").innerHTML = request.response;
}
</script>
```